# Нужна регулярка, для обязательного использования пробела. пример 'cardholder name'

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, html5

```css
.t { margin-bottom: 0.5em; border: 1px solid #ccc; outline: none; }
.t:focus { border-color: #abf; }
.t:valid { border-color: #9d0; }
```

```html
<input class="t" pattern='^[a-zA-Z]+$' required>
```

Comment: Может, `pattern="[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+"`? `pattern="[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)?"`? Какие именно требования к шаблону? Ваше выражение не разрешает использовать пробелы вообще. Заметьте, что тут `^` и `$` не нужны.

Comment: pattern='[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+$' нужен такой код,спасибо за внимание

Comment: Нет, $ не нужен.

Comment: но с $ работает)))

Comment: Да, только какой смысл заставлять движок дважды проверять одно и то же в одном и том же месте? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон `\s` находит любые пробельные символы, `\s+` находит любые 1 и более пробельных символов.

Можно использовать `pattern="[A-Za-z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+"`:

```css
.t { margin-bottom: 0.5em; border: 1px solid #ccc; outline: none; }
.t:focus { border-color: #abf; }
.t:valid { border-color: #9d0; }
```

```html
<input class="t" pattern="[A-Za-z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+" required>
```

В атрибуте `pattern` движок HTML5 "обёртывает" шаблон в `^(?: ... )$` и `pattern="[A-Za-z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+"` будет скомпилирован как `new RegExp("^(?:" + шаблон + ")$")`. В  Chrome и Firefox добавляется флаг `u`: `new RegExp("^(?:" + шаблон + ")$", "u")` - будьте начеку.

**Подробности**

- `^(?:` - начало строки и начало незапоминаемой (незахватывающей) подмаски
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 и более букв ASCII
- `\s+` -  1 и более пробельных символов
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 и более букв ASCII
- `)$` - конец подмаски и конец строки.

[**Демо регулярного выражения**](https://regex101.com/r/ulQjIo/2)

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ. просто the best!
 Если не секрет откуда у вас столько знаний о регулярных выражениях? можете кинуть хотябы одну ссылку на русский ресурс где описываются все случаи использования 'pattern' если такое возможно

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович Честно говоря, всё, что я знаю, я прочитал в сети на английском или отвечал на вопросы на английском SO. На русском языке в основном цитируют [Википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Есть [такой сайт о регулярках в JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript). Мне очень нравятся англоязычные http://regular-expressions.info и http://rexegg.com.

Comment: Можете также почитать [Джеффри Фридла](http://xn----etbevhopy.xn--p1ai/upload/gallery/354/29354_442cd06f258c6d7ec9177a663272d5b61e862ff5.pdf).

Comment: Cпасибо большое, столько много полезной информации, буду поскорее вникать и вспоминать о вас добрым словом!

Comment: а не подскажите на последок регулярку, для такой записи "1234 1234"

pattern="[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}" мой вариант не работает

Comment: 4 цифры, пробел(ы), 4 цифры? [`pattern="\d{4}\s+\d{4}"`](http://jsfiddle.net/zo7tjs61/).

Comment: Спасибо еще раз! Я сильно вдохновлён Вашими знаниями

Answer (score 0):

```css
.t { margin-bottom: 0.5em; border: 1px solid #ccc; outline: none; }
.t:focus { border-color: #abf; }
.t:valid { border-color: #9d0; }
```

```html
<input class="t" pattern='[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+$' required>
```

Comment: Вот, оказалось всё просто